# fastlane not work on jenkins pipeline but work on terminal (ERROR: PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks)

Tags: react-native, jenkins, fastlane

**i run fastlane through jenkins pipeline in got this errror PhaseScriptExecution**

i create fastlane to build react native. i run through terminal in server (mac M1) computer it work but when i run through jenkins pipeline, i got this error.

```
         [33mthe transform cache was reset.[0m
[33m▸[0m [39;1mRunning script[0m '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'
[33m▸[0m [39;1mRunning script[0m '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/HP1121-abc/abc_Build_Mobile/All_abc_Mobile_NP/ios/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/abc-project-dev/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/abc-project.build/DEV-iphoneos/abc-project.build/Script-191F2A2B45AD251EB5AE2D5D.sh (in target 'abc-project' from project 'abc-project')
(1 failure)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Failed to create symlink at /Users/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/HP1121-abc/abc_Build_Mobile/All_abc_Mobile_NP/ios/build/abcprojectApp.result.xcresult - a file already exists.
ERROR [2023-07-24 21:26:30.17]: [31mExit status: 65[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: 
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: [33mMaybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: [33mFound multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: [33mMake sure you selected the right version for your project[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: [33mThis build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app'[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: [33mIf you want to update your Xcode path, either[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: 
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: ▸ [35mxcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: 
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: ▸ [35mxcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: 
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: - Manually update the path using
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: ▸ [35msudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.18]: 

+---------------+------------------------------+
|              [32m[33mBuild environment[0m               |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app |
| gym_version   | 2.214.0                      |
| export_method | enterprise                   |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk             |
+---------------+------------------------------+

INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: ▸ [35mCommand PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: ▸ [35mResult bundle written to path:[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: ▸ [35m  /Users/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/HP1121-abc/abc_Build_Mobile/All_abc_Mobile_NP/ios/build/abcprojectApp.result[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: 
ERROR [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: [31m⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: [33m  For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:[0m
WARN [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: [33m  /Users/jenkins/Library/Logs/gym/abc-project-abc-project-dev.log[0m
INFO [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: 
ERROR [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: [31mLooks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project[0m
ERROR [2023-07-24 21:26:30.21]: [31mIt's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how[0m
```

**Pls Help me. How can i fix it**

Comment: Did you able to find a solution to this issue?